# How to set a delay on a method

Tags: java, settimeout, delay

When i currently call my method

```
public void flip() {
    Image change = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(imageName[0])).getImage();

    ImageIcon card = new ImageIcon(change);

    imagelbl.setIcon(card); 
}
```

Currently when the method is called the code runs and the method works. This is perfect however i need there to be a delay of 1 second before the method runs. 
I have tried using setTimeout() but i was unsuccessful. How would i get this method to have a 1 sec delay before running?

Comment: *"I have tried using setTimeout()"* - The code shown is *not* JavaScript, but `setTimeout()` *is* JavaScript. Where and how is that method called?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not the same!

Comment: Just a hint: a "timeout" means "how long to wait before giving up". So such a method, even if it existed in Swing, would not do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Timer class for timing.

```
public void callerMethod() {
    System.out.println("Start");
     Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                delayedMethod();
            }
        }, 1000);
}


public void delayedMethod() {
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

Comment: Since the OP is using swing (based on the use of `ImageIcon`), it's better to use `javax.swing.Timer` than `java.util.Timer`, especially since the `flip` method changes a GUI element, which should only be done from inside the EDT.

Answer (score -1):

Use  `Thread.sleep(1000)` as the first line in `flip()` method.

Comment: Nothing to do with this question, but I have a personal dislike for Thread.sleep();

Comment: It's not just a matter of personal dislike. One should *never ever* use sleep in the EDT. That will delay the entire GUI.

Comment: In addition, the question was not about make the thread sleep, it was timing another method. With Thread.sleep() you also have to handle exceptions.

Comment: @pruntlar could you please elaborate why you have 'Personal' issue with Thread.sleep()?